# Hide drop down value based on selection of another drop down

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

Please suggest if below works as i want to hide a drop down value based on other drop down value selection , but it is not working as expected.

```
var dropdown1 = $(":input[title='Engagement Type']");

if(dropdown.find("option[value='Tracking Number request']")==true)
{
  dropdown1.find("option[value='CR(Change Request)']").remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the below change event of the first drop-down and hide the option of the second drop-down based on the selected value of the first drop-down.

Drop-down 1's ID = dropdown1

Drop-down 2's ID = dropdown2

```
   $("#drop-down1").change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            if(selectedValue === "Tracking Number request")
            {
                $("#drop-down2 option[value='CR(Change Request)']").remove(); 
            }       
    });
```

Comment: Hi how can i get Id for these columns? sorry but i am not aware much of it

Comment: Hi @Divya Sharma,  I tried this too it is not working :(

Comment: Are you getting the selected value of the first drop-down as expected? Also, does it go inside the 'if' condition? Also, which error are you facing exactly?

Comment: Nope it is not foinf inside if condition and the value is not getting hidden. did not get any error also

Answer (score 0):

you should just edit the condition in your if. Just use as below

```
if(dropdown.find("option[value='Tracking Number request']"))
{
  dropdown1.find("option[value='CR(Change Request)']").remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi , yes i tried it , but the value "change request" is getting removed irrespective of other column drop down value selection. I have two drop down fields , based on first drop down selection value - "Tracking number request" the second column drop down value "CR" should be removed . Note : I have multiple values in other drop down values , the value CR should not be shown only for "tracking number"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select title='Field A'>
  <option key="A">A</option>
  <option key="B">B</option>
  <option key="C">C</option>
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select[title='Field A']").change(function () {
           
                if ($("[title='Field A'] option:selected").text() == "A") {
                    $("[key='C']").hide()
                }
                
            });
        });

</script>
```